# Was Mirror Garak lying to Kira?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode [Crossover](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/443.htm), Garak says the following about Mirror Universe Kira:

> KIRA: What are you doing in my quarters, Garak?
>
> GARAK: She's never going to let you leave, you know. Can't you tell? **She's in love**.
>
> KIRA: What are you talking about?
>
> GARAK: **In love with you**, my dear. She's all
> a-twitter about you, can't talk about anyone else. You're the perfect gift for the girl who has everything. She's taken you into her heart like a Drathan puppy lig left on her doorstep. Who else could she share her deepest secrets with, tell her troubles to, trust with her life?

Was Garak lying to Kira or was Mirror Universe Kira really **in love** with Kira? It seems kind of odd to say that considering they are essentially the same person (minus their personalities).

If you look at the context, mirror Garak is attempting to manipulate Kira to betray mirror Kira, because mirror Kira trusts Kira:

> GARAK: I arranged the guard. Oh, she trusts you. As much as she trusts anyone. So who better to betray her?

If he meant mirror Kira saw Kira as a close trusted friend, why didn't he phrase it way?

Comment: Have you seen the *Loki* miniseries from Disney? Mmmhmm, it's like that.

Comment: @Adamant - I know the series, but haven't seen the show. Can you explain in the comments?

Comment: It’s seems kind of odd to say that someone’s the same as another person as long as you ignore their personality. Personality feels like quite a defining feature of a person.

Comment: It’s important to remember that ‘love’ means many different things in English, from lust, to camaraderie, to obsession. The overall behavior of mirror Kira WRT Kira does not seem like erotic or romantic love, but definitely fits obsession (consistent with her narcissism) and possibly some degree of camaraderie.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - I understand what you're saying, but I guess it's how you interpret in love with someone. Usually on TV shows when someone says **in love with you**, it's a big deal. If Garak meant, she likes you, or she trusts you more than anyone else, why didn't he say that?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - That's because I interpreted **in love** in simple terms. I viewed it as attraction, but it's weird because biologically, their the same, the only difference is personality.

Comment: @QueenSvetlana Because it’s nowhere near that benign, it’s an unhealthy obsession, but calling it that would have arguably been too strong for the observed behavior. And while ‘in love with you’ may be a big deal in a lot of TV shows, DS9 was never really that type of show, and the context doesn’t even really fit. And, of course, mirror Garak _may_ have thought it was something more than just trust (simple trust and friendship do not lead to the level of obliviousness he seemed to assume in mirror Kira, not with the rest of the background of betrayal she would know).

Comment: @ Ah! Upvoted, well said.

Comment: Garak is like Kenobi. How can you know he's lying? He's talking. Except in this case, he's right...

Comment: @NKCampbell Kenobi usually tells the truth to people he likes, from a certain point of view at least.  But Garak (in any iteration) is pretty much always lying, to everyone including himself often.  He's made a career out of it.  But also, everything he ever says is also true - *especially* the lies.

Comment: @QueenSvetlana: ah right right — you're saying it's weird to be attracted to someone who's biologically identical to you.

Comment: @NKCampbell: Garak sits on a throne of lies!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Correct!

Comment: Like a politician, this question can be answered by asking, "were his lips moving?".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Garak means exactly what he says. Mirror Kira's initial characterization was extremely narcissistic and self-centered, with a view of the world that essentially boils down to "Kira" and "everybody else". When regular Kira arrives, Mirror Kira's worldview becomes herself at the center, her twin a very close second, and everyone else very far away. As Nana Visitor explains in DVD commentary:

> When she comes over [to the prime universe] and meets Kira, she falls in love with Kira. My intention, always, was that it was pure narcissism. It was simply someone that looked like her.

> the Intendant's justification for life is in doing things for herself. She is completely the most self-involved, self-centered person, she's like a child in that sense, which makes her funny, but in her childish way, she cares so little for other people she thinks nothing of disposing of them, using them.

Our Kira is one of the few people - if not the *only* person - that Mirror Kira actually sees as a real person. Small wonder that she's interested in getting to know our Kira better...

> "I'd be very disappointed if you didn't find the major… intoxicating. After all, she is me… Or the next best thing to me." (6x08 Resurrection)